# Select dropdown doesn't update itself immediately on change of value of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a select dropdown which gets its data from array. This array is populated by the response of server:

```
myApp.controller('mController', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, contextRoot) {

    var dataObject = {}
    $scope.arr = []

    $.post(contextRoot + "/servlet", dataObject, function(dataStr) {

        var dataFromServer = $.parseJSON(dataStr);
        console.log(dataFromServer);

        if (dataFromServer["success"] == 1) {
            $scope.arr = dataFromServer["list"]
        } else {
            alert("Failure! " + dataFromServer["message"])
        }
    });

});
```

A sample value of `dataFromServer["list"]` is:

```
["    _alerts", "    Test2ControlDesk", "    aug15test", "    sample2", "    samplerolDesk"]
```

The problem is that the dropdown doesn't get populated immediately after receiving the response and takes some time.

The html code is following:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDataSource" ng-options="item as item for item in arr | orderBy:'toString()' " ></select>
```

Comment: @Jeroen the problem is that once the response is received, the dropdown should get populated immediately. But it takes another 5-10 seconds to get populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your using `jquery $.post` to get the data from server, and its something outside of angular knowledge, so you have to force angular to update the scope after that outside process,

to do that use [`$scope.$apply();`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) after the ajax success like,

```
$.post(contextRoot + "/servlet", dataObject, function(dataStr) {

  var dataFromServer = $.parseJSON(dataStr);
  console.log(dataFromServer);

  if (dataFromServer["success"] == 1) {

    $scope.arr = dataFromServer["list"];

    $scope.$apply(); // new line

  } else {

    alert("Failure! " + dataFromServer["message"])

  }
});
```

here is a good [article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) about `$apply()`

or the **BESTWAY IS**

use angular builtin [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service